# Is it possible to switch uitableviewgrouped and uitableviewplain with uisegmentedcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am developing an iphone app in which i have a **segmented control** that has details related to something like a book .

I want to show books menu tapping on books segment with **uitableviewplain** style .

but now I want another segment which should show the book vendor details with **uitableviewgrouped** .

how can i **manage** both these views with the segmented controller and mange the data source and delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the simplest way to do that is to create two UITableViews for each purpose and show/hide them according to segmented control value.
   In delegate and data source methods just check what tableview are you using, like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView == plainView){

   }
    if (tableView == groupView){
   }
 }
```

Comment: but for plain view how to disable the - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section method

Comment: Doesn't 
if (tableView == plainView)
   return nil;
do the trick? 
Spec says: "...A string to use as the title of the section header. If you return nil , the section will have no title"